# Graph QL default Value on input cannot be deserialized by fasterxml

Tags: java, graphql, fasterxml, graphql-java

I'm facing a problem using GraphQL in Java.
I'm trying to create an input type with some fields with default Value.
It looks like :

```
input Test {
    tests:[Int]
    job: String = "DEV"
}
```

And the input java object is :

```
public class Test {
    private List<Integer> tests;
    private String job;
}
```

With a default constructor, all getter/setters.

But when I try a query using this input :

```
{testInput(input:{tests:[0,1]){data}}
```

I get the following error :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
```

Of course I tried to use a custom deserializer annotation, etc. Nothing did the trick...
For all other String values (without any "default value" set), no problem. Always get an exception from fasterxml... Sees that StringValue to String cannot be deserialized ?
Anyone maybe has an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: not in type defs ... maybe by custom annotations ... default can be done in resolver

Comment: Btw I thought that default values will automatically fill the value inside my java object... no way really...? Because in the deserialization I saw the job=stringvalue(value=DEV)...

Comment: in graphql world ...I don't use java at all ... maybe using some middleware (before mapping/matching) converting this into variables if not provided